# Translate linux ssh config syntax to PuTTY and Git

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab, putty

I have to use a proxy to get from my computer to an external server. From there I ssh to a remote server and then hop to a final gitlab server so I can do git stuff.

Summary: Personal Computer -> Internal Server (Proxy) -> Remote Server -> Remote Gitlab Server === Now I should be able to use Git/SourceTree/etc to do "git stuff".

I have gotten this to work on Ubuntu (without having to go through the proxy) using the directions below but I need this capability on Windows (have to go through the proxy) hence PuTTY. This [website](https://monkeyswithbuttons.wordpress.com/2010/10/01/ssh-proxycommand-and-putty/) gave a pretty close representation of what I am looking at doing.

The linux instructions I got which don't account for the proxy are as follows:

1. Create the following ~/.ssh/config file:

   ```
   Host gitlab.TEMP.com
    User <your user id>
    ProxyCommand nc -x localhost:5555 %h %p
   ```
2. Create an ssh tunnel:

   ```
   ssh -D 5555 <your user id>@gitlab.TEMP.com
   ```
3. Adjust Socks Proxy on browser (this is just necessary to view the gitlab in a browser. Do this in your non-default browser (Explorer/Mozilla) as you won't be able to search the internet with this browser)

   ```
   localhost:5555
   ```
4. Login to Gitlab in connected browser and add rsa pair information
5. Clone repository

   ```
   git clone git@gitlab.TEMP.com:<your user id>/<project>.git
   ```

Important: I have been able get through the proxy and to the remote gitlab server to view the gitlab repository (i.e., steps 1-4 plus the missing proxy step) but I can not get Git (via Git Bash or SourceTree) to connect to the repository (step 5). I get the error:

```
ssh: connect to host gitlab.TEMP.com port 22: Connection refused
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Ideas and suggestions would be appreciated, pictures of the putty interface would give you 10 gold stars! :) Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With some input from some other awesome folk who aren't on Stack Overflow I have been able to successfully connect and work Git magic. The images below are the only things I needed to do with putty. This solution worked for Git Bash and in SourceTree.

In the Session Tab:

Insert the host name, use Port 22, and select SSH.

[image: Session Tab]

In the Proxy Tab:

Use the appropriate proxy type, hostname, and port. This information is dependent on your setup. The proxy I used was type HTTP.

[image: Proxy Tab]

The Tunnels Tab:

Make sure the  "Local ports accept connnections from other hosts" box is checked.Add the local host with a source port. I chose 2000 but not sure that matters. Add a dynamic 5555 as well. This allowed me to view the Gitlab server site in a browser and set up the rsa key (see step 3 in the original question).

[image: Tunnels Tab]

You should now be able to access the gitlab via your browser. If your rsa key pair is set up then go to your favorite Git application or Git bash and enter the following to clone the repo in your current working directory:

```
git clone ssh://git@localhost:2000/PROJECT.git
```

You may get a prompt to a yes/no question (type 'yes' then hit enter) and for your rsa key phrase. The local clone should then be created.

Hopefully that works for you like it did me!